# Console log highlighted text from embedded website?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hey guys I was wondering if there was a way to store highlighted text into a string variable from an embedded website? I haven’t found anything yet that has lead me to believe this is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer that Tim Down gave to this similar question: 
 [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

If by "embedded" you are referring to a frame or iframe, then you may have to alter the javascript selectors so that they select the content inside of the frame.

Comment: Thank you for this